# How to make Visual Studio 2012 call the native 64-bit Visual C++ compiler instead of the 32-bit x64 cross-compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++-2012

Visual Studio 2012 seems to always call the 32-bit version of `cl.exe` located at `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64`) instead of the 64-bit one located at `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64`.

I tried prepending `$(VCInstallDir)bin\amd64` to the beginning of the "Executable Directories" list in the *VC++ Directories* section of the `Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user` property sheet, but that doesn't work at all -- when I rebuild I get this error:

```
TRACKER : error TRK0002: Failed to execute command: "
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64\CL.exe"
@C:\Users\<my_profile>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf3d817cafe064ad28e7dd62b2cb591c3.rsp
". The operation identifier is not valid.
```

How can I make Visual Studio 2012 use the native 64-bit C++ compiler?

Comment: Is the question out of plain curiosity or are you asking because my reason for doing this actually affects the procedure for fixing the IDE?

Comment: Just plain curiosity.  I can't think of any reason to want to use the native 64 bit compiler.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Microsoft made it for a reason ;) I need to see if it can compile some of my projects faster.

Comment: 64 bit mode is normally slower than 32 bit.  You use 64 bit mode because your program is running out of space.  If you have C++ sources which can't be compiled with the 32 bit compiler because of a lack of space...  those are some pretty big programs.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Have you ever tried compiling Chromium?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I was told by VS developers at BUILD 2013 that if we use the native x64 compiler (vs cross-compiler) the incremental linking feature will have to do a full link less-often. So, yes, this is a useful exercise but I'm hitting the same error. Unfortunately, we did not have time to try it in the demo area at BUILD.

Comment: I have recently needed to force usage of the 64-bit linker because the 32-bit linker was thrashing to save memory while linking a big project. The 64-bit linker has more relaxed constraints and can make better use of available RAM.  If you throw in a few boost libraries, and enable iterator debugging then it's quite easy to get up to libraries of 800Mb+, even though the linker will finally boil it down to an executable of 10Mb

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This answer is a bit late to the party, but frustratingly there's still no good resource directly available from Microsoft's online documentation. It turns out to be easy, even if not totally convenient.

At the command prompt, type (changing the version of VS to your needs):

```
> set _IsNativeEnvironment=true
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" YourProject.sln
```

The clue for this is in the file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.targets
```

where it says

```
<SetEnv Condition="'$(_IsNativeEnvironment)' == 'true'"
        Name ="PATH"
        Value ="$(NativeExecutablePath)"
        Prefix ="false">
  <Output TaskParameter="OutputEnvironmentVariable" PropertyName="Path"/>
</SetEnv>
```

My project is generated by CMake, so I am usually at the command prompt for a few lines before I can open VS anyway. I have always started my CMake generators after first setting up the MSVC environment, so I honestly don't know if it's required or not, but you can optionally also do (before everything else):

```
> call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
```

and /or

```
> call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat"
```

Here's the link to the [original post on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6b352ea-12b6-4867-b86d-a052fbab1da4/how-can-switch-to-native-x64-compiler-to-compile-x64-program) where I finally found the answer.

Comment: Update: For VS2013, the environment variable has changed. It's now: 'set PreferredToolArchitecture=x64' See [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800059/isnativeenvironment-true-no-longer-works-on-visual-studio-2013-rc)

Comment: In VS2013 there's also a mechanism to set the change in the vcxproj file -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25626630/188414

Answer (score 0):

I was converting an old project from Win32 to x64 and came across this problem. 
I found two different ways on how to go around this:

**Method 1:**
 i. Got to: ***Project properties*** | ***General*** | ***Platform Toolset*** 
 ii. Change the value from '**Visual Studio 2012 (v110)**' to '**Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)**'

**Mehtod 2:**
i. Open configuration file `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props`
ii. Inside the `<ExecutablePath>` property group, I replaced the `$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64)` entry with `$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86)`

After *any* of these all worked fine.