# YourProject.sln Not a valid Win32 Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-7

I was trying to build one of my x86 projects in x64 and I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188380/how-to-make-visual-studio-2012-call-the-native-64-bit-visual-c-compiler-instea)

> set _IsNativeEnvironment=true
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" YourProject.sln

Now, I am getting the following error prompt when I try to open any of the visual studio solutions ....... is not a valid win32 application.

Note: I have been working on this solution for quite a while and there was no such problem.

Edit: My devenv.exe itself has got corrupted and it's size is 0 KB. I reckon that's the problem. Will try to reinstall visual studio and see if the problem persists.

Comment: A .sln file is a text file.  Try opening it in notepad and see if it looks OK.  Also, try opening a solution from within Visual Studio rather than via Explorer.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that now when I am trying to open any solution using visual studio I see the same prompt. When I am trying to open visual studio itself the following prompt occurs: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common 7 \IDE\devenv.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: If devenv.exe has become corrupted that could explain the problem.  Is Visual Studio the only application that is misbehaving?

Comment: Ya, only visual studio is misbehaving. Other x64 applications are working nice and fine.

Comment: Also devenv's size is 0KB when it should be something around 6-7 KB.

Comment: A repair installation might work, otherwise you may have to uninstall and reinstall.